# Column Validation Settings for a mandatory choice

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, syntax, validation-list-items

I have a SharePoint 2013 list with 3 dropdowns of which 1 must be selected. It doesn't matter which is selected as long as one of them has data. I tried to do the Validation Settings:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK([Initial Pleadings])=TRUE,IF(AND(ISBLANK([Memos or Motions])=TRUE,IF(AND(ISBLANK([Other Filings]=TRUE))
```

but it doesn't seem to take. I want a message to pop up saying that the user must select a document type. I'm having a hard time getting it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
   =OR(
       NOT(ISBLANK(FirstColumn))
       ,NOT(ISBLANK(SecondColumn))
       ,NOT(ISBLANK(ThirdColumn))
      )
```

You need `OR` rather than `AND`

More information about OR [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/OR-function-9a2a1cca-696f-4d19-a959-3943babd076f) and AND [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/AND-function-78956048-53c7-484a-ab0b-6e70d7f03400)

Comment: Note that OR itself returns a TRUE/FALSE so you can do without the IF statement

Comment: Perfect! That worked excellently!

Comment: @Kimberley, then mark his answer as the correct one.. that is how SO works. Note: Because SharePoint is loosly typed **0** is FALSE and any other number is TRUE; you could also do:``NOT(ISBLANK(FirstColumn)+ISBLANK(SecondColumn)+ISBLANK(ThirdColumn))``